# Uninstall python 2.7 from 10.8

Tags: macos, python

I've made the tragic mistake of downloading and installing python 2.7 from http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/ instead of using homebrew. Now vim won't launch, all kinds of things are screwed up, and I can't get rid of this mess.

How do I uninstall this nonsense? I'm on 10.8, so pkgutil --unlink no longer works.

Comment: Very unlikely this is the only cause as this installs into /usr/local which does not affect Apple supplied things (However homebrew does install into /us/local so all you homebrew could be messed up - which is why I would use fink or macports as they are separate)

Comment: It seems to have been the issue. I used `pkgutil --files` to find the files that the python install placed throughout my system and hunted them down manually. All issues are resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can use pkgutil on a file *you know for sure* came from the python 2.7 you installed you can do

```
pkgutil --file-info /path/to/the/file
```

Copy/paste the pkgid in

```
pkgutil --file pkgid
```

That will spit out a list of files that came with python 2.7 -- you can now go ahead and remove them (with all due care not to remove any unrelated file in the same directories etc).

Comment: This is what I ended up doing and it resolved it.

Comment: I noticed that you did solve the issue after I answered! :)